# How to provide modified context to nested components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component like a list which can contain another lists like itself or another components.

I want to provide value by this component to all nested components but not modify value of outer components.
Or other words, I need to provide to `DisplayContextValue` value of first of List above:

```
<List value="root">
    <DisplayContextValue />  #should be "root"
    <div>
        <List value="second">
            <DisplayContextValue />  #should be "second"
            <DisplayContextValue />  #should be "second"
            <List value="third">
                <div>
                    <DisplayContextValue />  #should be "third"
                    <DisplayContextValue />  #should be "third"
                </div>
            </List>
        </List>
    </div>
    <DisplayContextValue />  #should be "root"
</List>
```

Can you give me any advice?

Comment: you can't pass in the same prop to `DisplayContextValue`?

Comment: Nope for many reasons, one or both components probably will be HOCs, and i pass down ref to List component instead of just value, and DisplayContextValue can be deep nested by other component etc.(

Comment: I can be possible if `<List>` and  `<DisplayContextValue />` are styled-components.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your use case for nested levels, you can create a context inside the `List` component and add a provider there. The value of the context is directly relative to the first context react finds when searching up the tree and corresponds to your usecase.

To implement this, your List component needs:

```
import ListContext, { Provider } from "./ListContext";

function List({ value, children }) {
  return (
    <Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

`ListContext` simply being:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const ListContext = createContext(null);

export const Provider = ListContext.Provider;

export default ListContext;
```

From the display component, you can access the value with:

```
function DisplayContextValue() {
  const listContext = useContext(ListContext);
  return <p>{listContext}</p>
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58257908?file=List.js)

Comment: Thanks, never think that context values can be overwritten